# Filter two dynamic columns for two values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet where the columns are dynamic and i need to first find the column header and then filter the data, the code i have so far is as follows:

```
Sub DynamicFilter222()
SearchCol = "Measurement Profile"
SearchCol2 = "Count"

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(SearchCol, , xlValues, xlWhole)
Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Find(SearchCol2, , xlValues, xlWhole)


Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=rng1.Column, Criteria1:="=Shear Rated(gamma)/dt 
= 4 1/s", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="

Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=rng2.Column, Criteria1:="Viscosity", 
Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="


End Sub
```

However only the second part works, if i delete the second part then the first will filter properly

So for definition:
I need to search the row A1 for the column headers (Measurement profile and Count) and once found, I need to filter Measurement profile column to only include BLANKS and "Shear Rated(gamma)/dt = 4 1/s" and the Count column to only include BLANKS and "Viscosity"

Thanks a lot for any assistance i have tried to use Application.Worksheetfunction.Match but no avail so far I think im struggling with the syntax,

thanks for any help!!

```
Dim rng As Range, res As Variant, count As Variant
Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet  

res = Application.Match("=Measurement Profile", rng, 0)
count = Application.Match("Count", rng, 0)

If Not IsError(res) Then
rng.AutoFilter Field:=res, Criteria1:="=Shear Rated(gamma)/dt = 4 1/s", 
Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="="
End If

If Not IsError(count) Then
rng.AutoFilter Field:=count, Criteria1:="Viscosity", Operator:=xlOr, 
Criteria2:="="
End If

End Sub
```

Tried this and it gives "Type Mismatch error" on "Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet" *(Line 2)*

This issue has been solved using the below solution changing
"Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet" to  "Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(1)"

However, I am now getting the issue whereby only one column is filtered, the "Count" column is filtered perfectly to show only "Viscosity" and "Blanks" however the "Measurement profile" column is showing everything not just "Shear rated (gamma)4 1/s" and "Blanks"

Comment: it should help if you show your attempt at using `Application.Worksheetfunction.Match` along with its issues (error messages and/or unexpected results)

Comment: Dim rng As Range, res As Variant, count As Variant
Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet  

res = Application.Match("=Measurement Profile", rng, 0)
count = Application.Match("Count", rng, 0)
...............................
Gives "type mismatch" on rng=Activeworkbook.Activesheet

Comment: put that in the proper position of your question code

Comment: start changing `"Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet" ` to `"Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(1)` (if wanted header is to be found in row 1)

Comment: Wow thanks that's sorted the initial error out however im still getting an issue whereby only one of my columns is filtering - The "Measurement Profile" column remains unfiltered however "Count" is being filtered properly
Edit: added to main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) change

```
Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```

to

```
Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows(1)
```

since you (correctly) declared `Dim rng As Range`, while you are assigning it a worksheet object (`Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet`)

2) and change (possibly)

```
res = Application.Match("=Measurement Profile", rng, 0)
```

to

```
res = Application.Match("Measurement Profile", rng, 0)
```

Comment: @Hamster244, any feedback?

Comment: Hi DisplayName that works absolutely perfectly, thanks a lot you've saved me so many hours :), +1 to your response and thanks again mate